# http proxy in python, when and how exactly should I close connection?

Tags: python, http, https, proxy

For a school project I need to open a proxy server in python. My proxy server works and shows the page on the browser but the problem is that it doesn't close connections after page shown and no more requests sent. The problem happens specifically after Connect Requests that start a proxy tunnel so I don't know when should I close the connection between the client and the server.
When and how should I close the connection between them?

```
def get_data(sock):
data = b''
data_add = b'test'
try:
    while len(data_add) != 0:
        # receive data from web server
        data_add = sock.recv(4096)
        data += data_add
except Exception as e:
    print("2:" + str(e) + " ")
return data

def handle_connect_command(client_socket, my_socket):
request = b'test'
try:
    send_data(client_socket, b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
    while True:
        request = get_data(client_socket)
        send_data(my_socket, request)
        response = get_data(my_socket)
        send_data(client_socket, response)
except Exception as e:
    print("5:" + str(e))
print("Connection lost")
client_socket.close()
my_socket.close()

def threaded(client_socket):
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
request = b'Test'
try:
    while len(request) > 0:
        # data received from client
        request = get_data(client_socket)
        web_server, port, command = analyze_request(request)
        print(web_server + ' ' + str(port))
        my_socket = connect_to_server(web_server, port)
        if command.lower() == "connect":
            handle_connect_command(client_socket, my_socket)
            break
        else:
            send_data(my_socket, request)
            response = get_data(my_socket)
            my_socket.close()
            send_data(client_socket, response)
except Exception as e:
    print("6:" + str(e))
# connection closed
client_socket.close()
my_socket.close()
```

Comment: can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using sock/sockets you can simply run:

```
server.quit()
```

or

```
session.close()
```

if you're using requests.

after creating a server object.

The matter of WHEN to close the connection is something we would need to see your code for.

logically you would close the connection when no more interaction needs to take place

Comment: is he using sockets, is he using Requests?

Comment: was thinking that myself so updated my response! i dont have permissions to simply make comments yet otherwise i wouldn't have actually submitted an "answer" but here we are -.-

Comment: i am using sockets

Comment: It looks like you're missing socket.close() in some of your while loops. the while loops should run through a series of commands and then close the connection, instead of only closing the connection if they encounter an error. otherwise the connection will stay open until an error is encountered

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Requests library (and you should) you can do this.

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get('target_url')
```

This will close the connection automatically when everything in the with condition completes.